# How to remove duplication of button in uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios

I am a newbie. I have created a `UITableView` and I have added a `UIButton` in a particular row (for example, in the second row) using the code given below. I am getting a duplicate of a button in the table when I scroll the table view.

Thanks in advance please give me a solution.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    if (indexPath.row ==1) {
    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2) + CELL_HEIGHT;
    }
    else{
        return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    UILabel *label = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
        [label setTag:1];


      //  [[label layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];





    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
    }


      if (indexPath.row==1) {

            UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            //Button.frame = CGRectMake(120, 120, 80, 24);
           NSString *text =@"BUTTON" ;
          CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

          CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


          Button.frame = CGRectMake(65, 150, 160, 24);

          [Button addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(load)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
           Button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            [Button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
               [cell addSubview:Button];
        }
    NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

   CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if (!label)
        label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [label setText:text];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: use  [cell.contentview addSubview:Button];

Comment: its working , if yes have a happy day

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - That makes no difference -- just a different way to say the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting multiple buttons is because you are adding a button instance into the cell every time you cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.  This call happens quite often and cells are reused (dequeued).

The proper way to deal with custom cells is to subclass cell and then set the appropriate cell when the right index is requested:

```
if (index == 1) {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"**Cell**"];
else {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"**OtherCell**"];
}
```

Comment: Or, if the button is in cells based on some cell attribute, keep a flag in the dataSource to know which cell type to dequeue.